# Make sure that back button won't navigate to signup page once signup was success?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic mobile app. I have signup page. Once a user's signup is success user will be navigated to profile page. Now what i want, once user is successfully signed up, users are not allowed to get back to signup page.

How can I make sure that back button won't navigate to signup page once signup was success ?

One solution I have is, to check for some condition every time signup page is loaded and based on that condition stay or navigate to other page. e.g.

```
if(userIsLoggedin()) {
  $state.go('home')
}
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: if you are already logged in then going to signup page doesn't make any sense ?

Comment: Probably not. But why do you care? There's nothing useful that will result from what you are trying to do and you risk bugs that will prevent users to visit the sign up page.

Comment: Ok let say you just after signup you came to profile page, now you pressed back button. Would you like that happen ?

Comment: Yes, because the user wants to get the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a factory to store data

```
    module.factory('DataStore', [function () {
        var _local = {}, dataStore = {};
        dataStore.setValue = function (field, value) {
            _local[field] = value;
        };
        dataStore.getValue = function (field) {
            return _local[field] || null;
        };
        return dataStore;
    }])
```

Then once you validate that the user is registered you set the flag in DataStore

```
module.controller('registration', function(..., DataStore) {   
    ...
    //do all necessary logic
    if(allGood) {
        DataStore.setValue('RegistrationSuccessful', true);
    }
});
```

Then anytime you can check from any other controller that imports DataStore

```
module.controller('home', function(..., DataStore) {   
    ...
    //do all necessary logic according to the code in your question
    $scope.onbtnclick = function () {
        if(DataStore.getValue('RegistrationSuccessful')) {
            $state.go('home')
        } else {
            $state.go('registration');
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by handling back button in ionic app. Check the app state on back button click if it's on profile page then do nothing so it will prevent default back event.

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
       if($state.current.name!="menu.profile" ){
            $ionicHistory.goBack(-1);
       }else{
          // if state is profile then control will be here.
       }
}, 100);
```

Put this code in app.js file.

Other suggestion: once user is register and login in to profile then he or she should be taken to profile page directly on app start.

you can do this in your register or verification function if user is not register then take it to signup page. and if user is logged in the take it to profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good. I think you may also want to make sure you check the user session on the server side.

Comment: Its mobile app not a statefull application

Comment: Oh I see. If its mobile app, it's even easier, for example, for Android app, you may need to create a fragment for signup, and anothet fragment for the home screen. Upon starting the app, check whether the user is logged in and select the fragment to add to your view accordingly.